# How to get all Docker containers even the ones who aren't running?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-container

I'm trying to implement a button to start all the stopped containers.
To do this thing I use [Dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode), I have already made a similar thing to stop all the containers and it works.

So to start them I used the same logic but it looks like         `docker.listContainers(function(err, containers) {}` only returns the running containers.

How can I get all the containers ?

This is my code but it's not useful for the question:

```
docker.listContainers(function(err, containers) {
            if (err) {

            } else {
                containers.forEach(function(containerInfo) {
                  console.log(docker.getContainer(containerInfo.Id));
                    docker.getContainer(containerInfo.Id).start(function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {

                        } else {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think I have founded `docker.listContainers({all: true}, function(err, containers)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'll post the answer because I'm sure I won't be the only one who'll search for that.

There is this code in the [example](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode/blob/976fe4ca205a4f48cd8628f7daf796af8017c705/examples/listContainers.js) folder:

```
docker.listContainers({all: true}, function(err, containers) {
  console.log('ALL: ' + containers.length);
});
```